# how to modify value declared in xml file in android at run time

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to get and set the value of controls define in XML Layout file at run time and save that value in another XML file .
i want to modify the state of the screen objects, including those declared 
in XML, at run time.
Thanks and Regards
RizN81

Comment: question was not clearly. can more elaborate what exactly you want to try?

Comment: At run time, you can't change any values in any resource files. What problem are you trying to solve that makes you want to try this?

Comment: Please be more specific describing your question

Comment: @TedHopp agree!! XML layout file can't updated by using code, but you can set individual attributes of any views by code.

Comment: i want to get values from the XML files (layout) and then save that value in another XML file(e.g AppSettings) and then use that value store in the XML file(e.g AppSettings) in any Class of my APP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to define the values you want to capture separately from the layout files. Then you can retrieve the values directly. For instance:

**some layout file**

```
<Button
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/left_padding"
    android:checked="@bool/default_checked"
    . . .
    />
```

**some file in res/values**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="left_padding">3dp</dimen>
    <bool name="default_checked">true</bool>
    . . .
</resources>
```

**In view code**

```
Resources res = getResources();
int leftPadding = res.getDimension(R.dimen.left_padding);
boolean defaultChecked = res.getBoolean(R.bool.default_checked);
```

You can then save `leftPadding` and `defaultChecked` in an XML file (but not a resource file!), in shared preferences, etc. But I think it would be easiest to just retrieve the resource value directly each time you need it.

Comment: ok but what if i define the value in xml layout(for eg:android:checked="true")  and want to store that value in another file?

Comment: i want to save the `3dp` value in to resources take from EditText at runtime from xml.

Comment: @RizN81 - You can do the same thing with boolean values (and just about any attribute value). (I updated my example to show this.) See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html) for all the other resource types you can define.

Comment: @RizN81 - Why do you need to save the `3dp` value again? It's already there as a resource value.

Comment: you not understand what i am saying .you define the value in resources file but i want to get that value from the user and then save the value in resources file.

Comment: @RizN81 - Ah. I think that's the first time you said that the values are coming from the user. Before you said that the values were coming "from the XML files (layout)". As I said before, you cannot modify resource files at run time. You can use the user-supplied values to set view and layout properties through the API. Almost every XML attribute has a corresponding API method for setting the value. (A few attributes require a different approach. For instance, `android:onClick` requires setting an `OnClickListener`.)

Comment: oh now my problem is i have a Toggle Button in XML Layout File and what i want is when user Click on its the value of Toggle button i.e `android:Checked` is change for example if the Value is True its Become False now this Value i want to store in the resources file .Its is possible or Not if Yes can you tell me the way to do that